# can't upload and unlink image php

Tags: php, upload, unlink

i have any problem in proccess to upload and unlink my image in server. i use this script to **upload image** :

```
move_uploaded_file($source, $directory);
```

but, i have warning :

> Warning:move_uploaded_file(34160518200001.jpg)
>   [function.move-uploaded-file]: failed to open stream: HTTP wrapper
>   does not support writeable connections

and i use this script to **unlink image** :

```
unlink('a34160518200001.jpg');
```

but i have warning :

> Warning:  unlink() [function.unlink]: http does not allow unlinking

i wish anyone can help me, thanks Master

Comment: It seems file permission issue

Comment: Set upload folder to 777. I am sure it is currently set to 775

Answer (score 0):

Here is an Example to get you started:

```
    <?php
        // NOT NECESSARY TO CREATE VARIABLES FOR THE IMAGES DIRECTORY
        // AND THE IMAGE BUT THIS HELPS ILLUSTRATE THE PROCESS.. ;-)
        $imagesDir  = "path/to_the/images/folder";
        $image      = "the_image_to_upload.jpg";

        // FIRST chmod THE IMAGES DIRECTORY TO HAVE THE PERMISSIONS YOU WANT:
        chmod($imagesDir, 0777);        

        // THEN UPLOAD THE IMAGE:
        move_uploaded_file($image, $imagesDir);

        // TO DELETE (unlink) A FILE [IMAGE IN THIS EXAMPLE]
        $image2Delete = "the_image_to_delete.png";

        // CHMOD THE IMAGE TOO... BE SURE ALSO THAT THE CONTAINING DIRECTORY
        // FOR THIS IMAGE ALSO HAS THE RIGHT PERMISSIONS:
        chmod($image2Delete, 0777);

        // THEN DELETE THE IMAGE...
        unlink($image2Delete);
```